# How can I replace part of a string in Lua?

Tags: lua, gsub

I have this string in Lua:

```
"The |cffffffffcar|r is here."
```

How can I use `string.gsub()` to replace whatever is between `|cffffffff` and `|r` with a different word?  Note that it won't necessarily be `car`, it could be any word that I need to replace but it will always be between `|cffffffff` and `|r`.

I don't know how many words will be before or after the word to replace so I can't do simple word counts or character counts. The GSUB has to replace whatever is between `|cffffffff` and `|r` no matter where they are in the string.  That's the key to the solution.

Thanks.

Comment: `input:gsub("(|cffffffff)[^|]*(|r)", "%1another-car%2")`  Remove `%1` and `%2` to remove color tags

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works perfectly.  I'm very impressed and pleased.  If you put this answer into a separate comment, I can mark it so you get credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Egor Skriptunoff posted the correct answer but I'm unable to mark it as it was in a comment thread.  If Egor moves it to an answer, I'll change my mark.

But this is what Egor suggested and it worked perfectly, it did everything I wanted so Egor was incredibly helpful.  Thank you Egor.

```
input:gsub("(|cffffffff)[^|]*(|r)", "%1another-car%2")
```

Remove %1 and %2 to remove color tags

This is how I'm using Egor's solution in my code:

```
local myvar = "|cffffffff" .. "red car" .. "|r"
local newvar = "blue car"

myvar = gsub(myvar, "(|cffffffff)[^|]*(|r)",  "%1" .. newvar .. "%2")
print(myvar)
```

Comment: Note that this won't match if your content contains other special sequences, like `||`. To solve that you either need multiple passes or a more powerful system, like PEGs.

Comment: True but Egor's solution works for my original question.  I have updated my answer to include the actual code I'm using thanks to Egor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach using `gsub`:

```
input = "The |cffffffffcar|r is here."
s = string.sub(input, "^(.*)[|].*[|](.*)$", "%1|BLAH|%2")
print(s)
```

This prints:

```
The |BLAH|r is here.
```

The logic here is that we capture, in two separate capture groups, the text on either side of the two pipes `|`.  Then, we stitch together the output you want, using the two capture groups with the new string sandwiched in between the pipes.

Comment: How can I do it so it doesn't print | or r.
I want it to just print The BLAH is here.
Also you have [|] to check for | (a single character).  Is there any way to check for a word like [blah]?

Comment: @Egor Skriptunoff provided correct answer but many thanks for your help too.  It's good to get different angles to a problem.